# Updating UI controls from another class

Tags: c#, signalr

I am using SignalR to implement a notification system to exchange information between my application instances. I have the following hub class:

```
[HubName("OpenHub")]
public class OpenHub:Hub
{
    public void DetermineLength(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.RecieveNewInfo(newMessage);
        //How to use something like the following line?
        //concerning that Form1 is loaded at application startup
        //and I should not create a new instance
        //Form1.lstMessages.Add(newMessage);
    }
}
```

Yet, I have to update some UI controls including a label and a listbox to log whatever new information that has arrived. Besides defining my class in my form's code, how can I update Form object to show these new information when I have my hub defined in a different class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use public static property in you `Program` class or you `Form1` class to hold the reference for it.

For example in you `Program` before using `Application.Run(new Form1());`

You can do this:

```
public static Form1 MainForm { get; set; }
```

and then in the `Main()`

```
MainForm = new Form1(); 
Application.Run(MainForm);
```

From the hub you can access you form now:

```
[HubName("OpenHub")]
public class OpenHub:Hub
{
    public void DetermineLength(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.RecieveNewInfo(newMessage);

        Program.MainForm.lstMessages.Add(newMessage);
    }
}
```

Of course, that `lstMessages` should be public. or better you expose in your form some public method to communicate with it.

Comment: I tried this one first and it works fine. The main problem was to access form controls from another class, which you helped to define in a static class. Does this mean if I define other objects in another static class I'll be able to access them too?

Comment: You can add more static members to the Program or to the Form. But be careful from going too static. Build a sensible class hierarchy. And get the access to its root.

Comment: You saved me after 3 hours of searching. thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

If your app is winform you can register to the hub with something like this :

```
var Connection = new HubConnection("yourSignalRServerUrl");      
var HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("OpenHub"); 

HubProxy.On<string>("RecieveNewInfo", (message) => 
    this.Invoke((Action)(() => 
      Form1.lstMessages.Add(message);
);

await Connection.Start();
```

The namespace needed to use HubProxy is `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client`

This example comes from : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b

Comment: I think the OP is talking about the server, not the client